# How to set the body of a http post request in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rest, post

I'm trying to post to a restful service with Matlab. I've tried using webread, webwrite, and urlread and I cannot figure out how to set the body of the message.

My body is json and looks like this:

`{"Item1": "string1", "Item2": "string2"}`

Comment: You're trying to post to the service, so have you tried `webwrite` instead of `webread`?

Comment: Yes I have. Sorry for not listing that. I also tried webread with post in the weboptions object.

Comment: Have you tried passing the item names and values separately as outlined in the first paragraph of the documentation? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html

Comment: Yes, it returns a 500 error :/

Comment: I'm using postman to log in and it works fine. But, because I am working from a vpn, I cannot use fiddler to intercept my web traffic and analyze it.

Comment: I haven't used postman. Have you tried posting to some other service via Matlab just to make sure it's not a problem on your side and the syntax you're using is all correct?

Comment: I already answered the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. I was constructing my body as a string literal and not as a matlab struct. Correct way:

```
api = 'http://myurl.net';
url = [api, '/Login'];
[un, pw] = GetAuthentication;
input = struct('Username',un,'Password',pw);
opts = weboptions('MediaType','application/json');
userInfo = webwrite(url, input, opts);
```